# Heroku - Migration failing, how to change migration to run on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've got a migration file which does the following:

```
class ChangeLoginToUsername < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_column :users, :login, :string
    add_column :users, :username, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :username, :string
    add_column :users, :login, :string
  end
end
```

This ran in fine on my local dev but I've now noticed the third parameter for the filed type on remove_column is erroring when I try and run  this migration on Heroku. Is there a way to write/run specific migrations just for Heroku? There are 2 further migrations after this one that I need to run...

Any help hugely appreciated as always

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense for `remove_column` to have a data type:

```
class ChangeLoginToUsername < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_column :users, :login
    ....
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :username
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I know - If you read above I've noticed this, but it's already a migration file which ran fine on my local dev enivronment, I just don't know how to change it to run it on Heroku :(

Comment: I don't think I understand what the problem is? Why don't you remove the 3rd param and run the migration ?

Comment: I already ran the migration on development and it worked, if I edit the migration file and try to run it on Heroku it doesn't update and still tries to run the old file - any ideas?

Comment: Re-run `db:setup` after dropping the database.

Comment: I managed to somehow bug around it and just use some git commands to get the different version there and run it, then heroku restart - seems to be ok now, thanks though